Script to stop MySQL
I want to be able to stop and start my MySQL installation from the MySQL Workbench. Initially it said the the start/stop scripts were missing. After a couple of days I've found where these should go and created some. Whilst the shell scripts I've created do stop and start the server from the command line they do not work when called form the Workbench. I get:
2024-11-11 10:12:16 - MySQL server is currently running
Could not open error log file: Could not get data from file /var/log/mysql/error.log
2024-11-11 10:14:54 - Stopping server...
2024-11-11 10:14:54 - Executing '/home/neil/tools/downServer.sh'
2024-11-11 10:14:54 - Stop server: /bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/sudo: Permission denied

2024-11-11 10:14:54 - Server stop done.
2024-11-11 10:14:54 - Checking server status...
2024-11-11 10:14:54 - MySQL server is currently running
2024-11-11 10:14:54 - Checking server status...
2024-11-11 10:14:54 - MySQL server is currently running

The error log file has permissions of 666 so I don't understand why it can't open that file.
Why can it not execute sudo and if not how do I execute that command in a script?

By running the script from the command line you inherit the permission from the user running it but when MySQL Workbench run it, it doesnt have those permission and also it cant run sudo since it is a GUI.
The easiest solution would be use configure sudo to allow execution without password.
we gonna use visudo in your terminal like this:
sudo visudo

then we add this line at the end of your file, dont forget to replace /path/to/mysqladmin by the path to the command you need to run, for example /usr/bin/mysqladmin
neil ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/mysqladmin, /path/to/other/commands

Also check that Defaults requiretty is disabled in the sudoers file, it should be like this in the file:
Defaults:neil !requiretty

Then you gonna have to check that your script use the full path to the command, like:
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/mysqladmin shutdown


Thanks. It now shuts down OK. It was starting OK but no I get:

/etc/sudoers:45:47:syntax error
neil All=(All) NOPASSWD /usr/bin/mysqladmin

I've tried to start the server with mysqladmin but there doesn't seem to be a command that does that!

You have a syntax error in your sudoers file it is case sensitive, All should be ALL, like this: neil ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/mysqladmin
